# JavaFX custom TreeView with ComboBox

Tags: javafx, combobox, treeview

I try to create a TreeView that will have on every branch and leaf a ComboBox, an "add child" Button and an "remove child" Button.
Here is my code

```
package example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author me
 */
public class Example extends Application {
  
String[] companyNames = new String[10];     
    
    
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        
   companyNames[0]="FORD";    
   companyNames[1]="MG";
   companyNames[2]="LADA";
   companyNames[3]="BMW";
   companyNames[4]="KIA";
   companyNames[5]="HYUNDAI";
   companyNames[6]="AUDI";
   companyNames[7]="MERCEDES";
   companyNames[8]="DACIA";   
   companyNames[9]="TOYOTA";   
   
   
   final TreeItem<String> treeRootItem = new TreeItem<>("Root");
   final TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(treeRootItem); 
    
   treeRootItem.setExpanded(true);    
   treeView.setCellFactory(e -> new CustomCell()); 
   
   VBox mainVBox = new VBox();
   
   mainVBox.getChildren().add(treeView);     
    
   Scene scene1 = new Scene(mainVBox,1600,600);
   primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
   primaryStage.show();
   primaryStage.centerOnScreen();      

    }    
    
    //function custom TreeCell CustomCell 
    class CustomCell extends TreeCell<String> {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) 
    
    {

    ComboBox companiesComboBox = new ComboBox();
    Button addChildButton = new Button("Add Child");
    Button removeButton = new Button("Remove Child");

    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (isEmpty()) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                    setText(null);
                    } 
    else {

          HBox cellBox = new HBox(10);

          if (item.equals("Root"))
          {
            cellBox.getChildren().addAll(companiesComboBox,addChildButton);
          }
        
          else  cellBox.getChildren().addAll(companiesComboBox,addChildButton,removeButton);

          setGraphic(cellBox);
          setText(null);
          }
        
        
    companiesComboBox.getItems().addAll((Object[]) companyNames);
        

    addChildButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        
    String selection=companiesComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();
    TreeItem<String> childNode1 = new TreeItem<>("Child Node");
    getTreeItem().getChildren().add(childNode1);

    }});   
              
    removeButton.setOnAction(value ->  { 
    //somehow i will remove the leaf/branch    
    });   
        
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

(As Alexandra pointed out, in my prior post, i had many Java Naming Conventions wrong, i hope i fixed it now.
A am sorry that i deleted my prior post but it was off topic with many wrongs so i decided to make a small research how to make a post with better code and more specific without mistakes and come back a few days later.I hope that now is presentable.)
The problem that i have is that when i add a new child , the hole tree loses the ComboBox selection.
Here is a picture of the project running https://ibb.co/8MVDqhX
Any help/suggestion will be appreciated

UPDATE:
After Slaw answer i tried to create a Model Class named SelectedCompanyClass

```
package example;

import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

/**
 *
 * @author me
 */
public class SelectedCompanyClass {
    

    public String companyNameString;

    public SelectedCompanyClass(String companyNameString) {
        this.companyNameString = companyNameString;
    }
        
}
```

And i changed my main class like this

```
package example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author me
 */
public class Example extends Application {
  
String[] companyNames = new String[10];     
int x=0;        
SelectedCompanyClass SelectedCompanyClass1;   


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
     
    this.SelectedCompanyClass1 = new SelectedCompanyClass("root");
        
   companyNames[0]="FORD";    
   companyNames[1]="MG";
   companyNames[2]="LADA";
   companyNames[3]="BMW";
   companyNames[4]="KIA";
   companyNames[5]="HYUNDAI";
   companyNames[6]="AUDI";
   companyNames[7]="MERCEDES";
   companyNames[8]="DACIA";   
   companyNames[9]="TOYOTA";   
   
   
   final TreeItem<SelectedCompanyClass> treeRootItem = new TreeItem<>(SelectedCompanyClass1);
   final TreeView<SelectedCompanyClass> treeView = new TreeView<>(treeRootItem); 
   
   treeRootItem.setExpanded(true);    
   treeView.setCellFactory(e -> new CustomCell()); 
   
   VBox mainVBox = new VBox();
   
   mainVBox.getChildren().add(treeView);     
    
   Scene scene1 = new Scene(mainVBox,1600,600);
   primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
   primaryStage.show();
   primaryStage.centerOnScreen();      
   System.out.println("Start runs");
   
    }    
    

    class CustomCell extends TreeCell<SelectedCompanyClass> {
    
    protected void updateItem(SelectedCompanyClass SelectedCompanyClass1, boolean empty) 
    
    {

    ComboBox companiesComboBox = new ComboBox();
    Button addChildButton = new Button("Add Child");
    Button removeButton = new Button("Remove Child");

    super.updateItem(SelectedCompanyClass1,empty);
    
    if (isEmpty()) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                    setText(null);
                    } 
    else {

          HBox cellHBox = new HBox();

                    if (SelectedCompanyClass1!=null)
          {  
          if (SelectedCompanyClass1.companyNameString.equals("Root"))
          {
            cellHBox.getChildren().addAll(companiesComboBox,addChildButton);
          
          }
          else  cellHBox.getChildren().addAll(companiesComboBox,addChildButton,removeButton);
          companiesComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(SelectedCompanyClass1.companyNameString);
          }
          setGraphic(cellHBox);
          setText(null);
          
          }
        

    companiesComboBox.getItems().addAll((Object[]) companyNames);
        

    addChildButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
    String selection="none";     

    SelectedCompanyClass SelectedCompanyClass2 = new SelectedCompanyClass(selection);
    
    if (companiesComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString()!=null) {
        selection=companiesComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();
        SelectedCompanyClass2.companyNameString=selection;
    }


    TreeItem<SelectedCompanyClass> childNode2 = new TreeItem<>(SelectedCompanyClass2);
    
    getTreeItem().getChildren().add(childNode2);
    childNode2.setExpanded(true);
    }});   
   
    removeButton.setOnAction(value ->  { 
    //somehow i will remove the leaf/branch    
    });   
    }
    
 
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    
}
```

Now, thanks to Slaw , i have made progress and i create new objects TreeItem as childs, but parent Node loses its ComboBox selection

UPDATE 2:
After the usefull suggestions, i finally done it, here is the code
The model Class code

```
package example;

import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;


public class SelectedCompanyClass {
String companyNameString = new String();    

    public SelectedCompanyClass() {
    companyNameString="Choose";
        
    }
}
```

and the Main code

```
package example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author me
 */
public class Example extends Application {
  
String[] companyNames = new String[10];     
int x=0;        


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
     
   SelectedCompanyClass SelectedCompanyClass1 = new SelectedCompanyClass();
        
   companyNames[0]="FORD";    
   companyNames[1]="MG";
   companyNames[2]="LADA";
   companyNames[3]="BMW";
   companyNames[4]="KIA";
   companyNames[5]="HYUNDAI";
   companyNames[6]="AUDI";
   companyNames[7]="MERCEDES";
   companyNames[8]="DACIA";   
   companyNames[9]="TOYOTA";   
   
   
   final TreeItem<SelectedCompanyClass> treeRootItem = new TreeItem<>(SelectedCompanyClass1);
   final TreeView<SelectedCompanyClass> treeView = new TreeView<>(treeRootItem); 
   
   treeRootItem.setExpanded(true);    
   treeView.setCellFactory(e -> new CustomCell()); 
   
   VBox mainVBox = new VBox();
   
   mainVBox.getChildren().add(treeView);     
    
   Scene scene1 = new Scene(mainVBox,1600,600);
   primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
   primaryStage.show();
   primaryStage.centerOnScreen();      
   System.out.println("Start runs");
   
   

   
    }    
    

    class CustomCell extends TreeCell<SelectedCompanyClass> {
    
    protected void updateItem(SelectedCompanyClass SelectedCompanyClass1, boolean empty) 
    
    {

    ComboBox companiesComboBox = new ComboBox();
    Button addChildButton = new Button("Add Child");
    Button removeButton = new Button("Remove");
    Label objectLabel = new Label();

    
        companiesComboBox.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        SelectedCompanyClass1.companyNameString=newValue.toString();
        });   
   
    
    
    super.updateItem(SelectedCompanyClass1,empty);
    
    if (isEmpty()) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                    setText(null);
                    } 
    else {

          HBox cellHBox = new HBox();

                    if (SelectedCompanyClass1!=null)
          {  
          cellHBox.getChildren().addAll(companiesComboBox,addChildButton,removeButton,objectLabel);
          companiesComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(SelectedCompanyClass1.companyNameString);
          }
          setGraphic(cellHBox);
          setText(null);
          
          }
        

    companiesComboBox.getItems().addAll((Object[]) companyNames);
        

        

    addChildButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
    String selection="none";     

    SelectedCompanyClass SelectedCompanyClass2 = new SelectedCompanyClass();
    
    TreeItem<SelectedCompanyClass> childNode2 = new TreeItem<>(SelectedCompanyClass2);
    getTreeItem().getChildren().add(childNode2);
    childNode2.setExpanded(true);


       companiesComboBox.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
       SelectedCompanyClass2.companyNameString=newValue.toString();
        }); 

    
    }});   
   
    removeButton.setOnAction(value ->  { 
    //somehow i will remove the leaf/branch    
    });   
    }
    

    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    
}
```

Best regards to all

Comment: Haven't analyzed your code in-depth, but my intuition tells me the problem is: _You don't have a model_. Since you don't have a model you're using the view to maintain the state and that's no good. Create a model and simply have the `TreeView<YourModel>` display the state of said model. Then interactions with the tree update _the model_ and the tree observes the model for changes in order to keep up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer Slaw, i will look into it

Comment: Don't create a new combo box in `updateItem()`; create one once for each cell instance (e.g. in the constructor) and set its selected value in `updateItem()`. But this makes absolutely no sense to me at all: in what sense is one company a child of another company? Also, please don't delete and essentially repost the same question; you should edit your old question.

Comment: Yes , thank you James_D i tried to add a constructor but i have not made it to work

Comment: Thank you Kleopatra, i have made a mistake in naming;  i read some articles and i tried to be correct in my code

Comment: _Don't create a new xx in updateItem()_ (as @James_D) suggested, holds for every type of node (also for the hBox!) ... but then: I think you should work through some basic tutorial on how to use javafx (even before trying out custom cells, you seem to be doing the n-th step before the 1.step - f.i. you seem to be querying the combo's selected item _before_ setting the items (or maybe that's just due to improper formatting, yet another field you need to put some more effort into) Also note, that there _is_ a ComboBoxTreeCell - you might get some ideas from it.

Comment: Thank you Kleopatra, i finally done it, i will update my code to include the proper code if someone needs something similar :)

Comment: please format your code, it's unreadable .. I suspect that you have a major flaw with the listener to the combo's value - you recreate the combo each time in updateItem (DONT DONT DONT), installing a listener to each which still might be active for an unpredictable time after the combo isn't used - but hard to tell with that crooked formatting (not having the patience to fix it, but then it's your job ;)

Comment: btw, just in case you are not aware of it: you can answer your own question (and later accept it)